# Circle won't draw in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am experimenting with sprites in pygame,
In this example, the circle is drawn successfully in this code :

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        # line required to propertly create the sprite
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        # create a plain rectangle for the sprinte image
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (50, 40))
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        # find the rectangle that encloses the image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.radius = 20
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, RED, self.rect.center, self.radius)
        # center the sprite on screen
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT - 50)

        self.speedx = 0
```

But it won't draw when I put it after modifiying my rectangle center like this :

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        # line required to propertly create the sprite
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        # create a plain rectangle for the sprinte image
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (50, 40))
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        # find the rectangle that encloses the image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.radius = 20
        
        # center the sprite on screen
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT - 50)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, RED, self.rect.center, self.radius)

        self.speedx = 0
```

Why is this the case ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, because you are drawing the circle on `self.image`. If you change the position of the rectangle, you are just changing the position where the image will later be `blit`. `self.image` has no location. It's just an *Surface* object, where the top left is always (0, 0).

In the following code the circle is drawn in the center of `self.image`

> ```py
> self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
> pygame.draw.circle(RED, self.rect.center, self.radius)
> ```

In the following, the circle will be drawn outside the boundaries of the `slef.image` *Surface* because the circle will be drawn at a position where the image will later be `blit`:

> ```py
> self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
> self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT - 50)
> pygame.draw.circle(self.image, RED, self.rect.center, self.radius)
> ```

The line `self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT - 50)` doesn't change `self.image`, it just changes the position where you draw the circle.